# StaggeredGridLayoutManager calculateCachedStart() IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, staggeredgridlayout

Hi I got error report from Fabric on my apps -> IndexOutOfBoundsException on StaggeredGridLayoutManager calculateCachedStart() method

There is many usage StaggeredGridLayoutManager on my apps.
Any idea to fix this error or trace which one in my apps that cause this?

Using compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:260)
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:313)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$Span.calculateCachedStart(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2457)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager$Span.getStartLine(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:2474)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.checkSpanForGap(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:410)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.hasGapsToFix(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:359)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.checkForGaps(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onScrollStateChanged(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:319)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView.java:4596)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setScrollState(RecyclerView.java:1371)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.cancelTouch(RecyclerView.java:2890)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2868)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8593)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2493)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2157)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2495)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2495)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2530)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2171)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1818)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2860)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2483)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4681)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4335)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4173)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4146)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6694)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6668)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6621)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6853)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:216)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6812)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6879)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:804)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:607)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5833)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: You have initialized your `ArrayList`but it has no elements in it.

Comment: How you fixed this? Thx.

Comment: Anyone solved this??

Answer (score 4):

If your `RecyclerView` is in a `Fragment` and your `Fragment` is in `ViewPager`, and you didn't set `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(MAX_ITEM_SIZE)`, this crash will some times happen unexpectedly.

I was suffering same crashes. I can't reproduce it, and don't know why it would happen till now. But after I set the off-screen page limit, this crash goes away.

Wish it helps.

Comment: Not helped for me :(

Answer (score 2):

It's part of StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java

```
  /**
     * Checks for gaps in the UI that may be caused by adapter changes.
     * <p>
     * When a full span item is laid out in reverse direction, it sets a flag which we check when
     * scroll is stopped (or re-layout happens) and re-layout after first valid item.
     */
    boolean checkForGaps() {
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || mGapStrategy == GAP_HANDLING_NONE || !isAttachedToWindow()) {
            return false;
        }
        final int minPos, maxPos;
        if (mShouldReverseLayout) {
            minPos = getLastChildPosition();
            maxPos = getFirstChildPosition();
        ....
```

For a workaround, we can prevent `StaggeredGridLayoutmanager.hasGapsTofix()` call (which is the reason for this crash).

```
staggeredGridLayoutmanager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```

But this option disables unexpected gap handling.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. In my case i had one "parent" RecyclerView and one of its items had its own "child" RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Crash was happening when ViewHolder connected to this item was recycled. Setting up [RecyclerView.ViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(kotlin.Boolean)) on this ViewHolder fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from any external source or API, then try using postDelayed() method when updating or initializing the recycler view, In my case
this solved the error.

```
val handler = android.os.Handler()
handler.postDelayed({
    RecyclerViewAdapter!!.update(ArrayList<SearchNewModel>)
}, 200)
```